Cannot invoke 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement' because 'Wait_Selenium.WaitElementToDisplay.driver' is null
Exception -
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "Wait_Selenium.WaitElementToDisplay.driver" is null
    at Wait_Selenium.WaitElementToDisplay.main(WaitElementToDisplay.java:15)

I am using import methods of a class below.
package BrowserFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class BrowserFactory_LaunchBrowser {
    public static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static WebDriver launchBrowser(String browserName) {
        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./exeFiles/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            System.out.println("Chrome Launched");
        } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecho.driver", "./exeFiles/gechodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            System.out.println("FireFox Launched");
        } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "./exeFiles/msedgedriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            System.out.println("Edge Launched");
        } else if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./exeFiles/IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            System.out.println("Internet Explorer Launched");
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");

        return driver;
    }

    public static void closeBrowser() {
        driver.close();
        System.out.println("Current Browser Closed");
    }

    public static void closeAllBrowser() {
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("All Browser Closed");
    }
 }

I have done import method. Now I want to wait until google searchbox is visible. Please tell me by using which code I can wait until that element is visible. Please also guide me how to resolve this kind of problem. Thanks.

package Wait_Selenium;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class WaitElementToDisplay {
  public static WebDriver driver;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException, Throwable {
      BrowserFactory.BrowserFactory_LaunchBrowser.launchBrowser("chrome");
      
      //WaitElementToDisplay test = new WaitElementToDisplay();
      Thread.sleep(5000);
      WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@aria-label='Search']"));
      if (searchbox.isDisplayed()) {
          System.out.println("Searchbox is visible :" + searchbox.isDisplayed());
      } else {
          System.out.println("Searchbox is not visible :" + searchbox.isDisplayed());
      }

      BrowserFactory.BrowserFactory_LaunchBrowser.closeBrowser();
  }                                                                                                   }


I don't know which code is creating this issue and issue is related to below class.
package Wait_Selenium;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Wait_Selenium {
    static WebDriver call;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
 "./exeFiles/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
        call = new ChromeDriver(co);
        call.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        call.manage().window().maximize();

        // Implicit Wait in Selenium
        call.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        call.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
        System.out.println("Browser Launched");
        String searchBox = "//textarea[@title='Search']";
        WebElement search = call.findElement(By.xpath(searchBox));
        search.sendKeys("Test Selenium");
        search.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        // explicit wait - to wait for the compose button to be click-able
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(call, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        String searched = "//div[starts-with(text(), 'Selenium')][@role='heading']";
    
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(searched)));
        System.out.println("Searched Item Displayed");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        call.close();
    }
}


usually you'd have only one "main" method as an entry point.  (that's why it takes args... for command line arguments when calling the executable) The exception here is because you don't do anything with the returned driver reference from your factory class.  So should be: driver =  BrowserFactory.BrowserFactory_LaunchBrowser.launchBrowser("chrome");  But you should probably not use "main" like a constructor.  Just use the class's name for constructor method to use proper dependency injection.
